# Modeling Reddit style Comments in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am looking into using DynamoDB to store comments for my application.  The comments will be a nested data structure like you would find in reddit. So users can rate and reply to any comment.  For example

Topic1

- Comment1

  - Reply1
  - Reply2
- Comment2

  - Reply1

My question is how do I model the Reply relationship in DynamoDB so I can query a topics comments and all subsequent replies without doing a lot of grouping on the backend.  This kind of data structure is obviously more suited to a Graph database but I am curious if anyone has tried to model a tree like data structure in DynamoDB.

Answer (score 1):

With document support introduced in late 2014, you can model tree data using Map and List types. Your thread depth would be limited by the maximum depth of JSON documents, currently at [32](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ServiceQuotas.html#limits-attributes-nested-depth). Alternatively, you could use the [DynamoDB Storage Backend for Titan](https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-titan-storage-backend) to model your message data as a graph. You get to decide how many hops you want your graph traversals to perform, so you get to decide the limit for thread depth.